# Conversion of Float value to 24 Bit

Tags: c#

I have a float value of 128.523 which needs to be expressed as 24 bit 2s Complement signed number.

The 23rd Bit is the sign bit.
Bits 22 to fifteen are the integer part.
Bits 14 to 0 are the floating part.

I need to send this data to a protocol which only accepts data in this format.

I understand that i need to give my code and ask answers but unfortunately i am totally lost as how to proceed forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** with the help of the community

- I would be getting tracking data from a external device and send it to a application which uses freeD protocol.I have
- There is no 24Bit float that is the problem , i have found out how the bits would be arranged if we make it 24 bit( user Class).
- I will send it via UDP
- I have no idea in what order the bits need to be sent

Update

It is Bigendian

Comment: Your first problem, there is no 24bit integers in C#, 2) since there is none, you need to tell us where you are using these integers (is it an unmanaged library for instance? is this big endian or little endian. what does the dll import for this method look like. and also, didn't you ask this the other day?

Comment: i would be getting tracking data from a external device and send it to a application which uses freeD protocol.I have

Comment: ok we are getting somewhere `send it to a application` how are you sending it?

Comment: there is no 24Bit float that is the problem , i have found out how the bits would be arranged if we make it 24 bit( user Class).

Comment: ok ill give you 3 bytes, in some random format, how is this going to help you?

Comment: i will send it via UDP.

Comment: Ok great, so bytes are fine

Comment: Is it big endian or little endian ?

Comment: The application receiving it will interpolate data according to the bits i have mentioned.

Comment: If you dont know the order of the bits you are going to have to try both ways

Comment: It is  Bigendian.

Comment: Because there is no official IEEE Standard for this float you are talking about, you will need the specs as its likely proprietary. I mean working out how to poke a value into a sign mantissa and exponent is not obvious

Comment: Do you have a wiki page or specs for the this 24bit float composition? , the bit offsets is just not enough information. I.e poking values into them is likely not going to be right

Comment: http://docs.vizrt.com/tracking-hub-guide/1.0/description_of_the_freed_protocol.html

Comment: if this doesn't help i can send you a document about the bit structure for the Byte.

Comment: Yeah you will need explicit specifications for the 24bit float. if you dont have them, maybe you can ask the people who wrote this FreeD stuff

Comment: this may be thought of as a signed integer value in
units of 1/32768 degree. The range of values is from -180.0 degrees (A60000
hex) to +180.0 degrees (5A0000 hex).

Comment: @shomit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407661/float-to-24-bit-integer-in-c-sharp/50407909#50407909) I gave you the methods to convert from and to, if I remember well...

Comment: Yes but it is 32 bit after conversation,  the end result should be 24 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the other [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50407909/613130) I gave you, the only problem then is to trucate the `Int32` to a `Int24`. The simplest thing would be to use the `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` that returns a `byte[4]` and then remove the last `byte`... Or we can use some special `struct`, like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Int32ToBytes
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint Uint32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Byte0;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Byte1;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Byte2;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Byte3;
}

public struct Int24
{
    public byte Byte0;
    public byte Byte1;
    public byte Byte2;
}
```

And then:

```
private const int minSrc = 0x5A0000;
private const int maxSrc = 0xA60000;
private const double minDest = -180.0;
private const double maxDest = 180.0;
private const double rangeDest = maxDest - minDest;

public static Int24 ConvertToInt24(double num)
{
    int res = (int)(((num - minDest) * rangeSrc / rangeDest) + minSrc);
    var conv = new Int32ToBytes { Int32 = res };
    var res2 = new Int24
    {
        Byte0 = conv.Byte0,
        Byte1 = conv.Byte1,
        Byte2 = conv.Byte2,
    };
    return res2;
}
```

Now, the `Int24` struct has 3 bytes, `Byte0`, `Byte1` and `Byte2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  , but by removing one byte won't this effect the data value.

Comment: @shomit That byte is always 0, given the range of valid values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.